# Enumerating all subsets with sum at most S

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

What is an efficient way to enumerate all subsets of a given list L of numbers, such that the sum of all numbers in the set is at most a constant S?

One option is to use [the recipe for `powerset` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), and then filter by the sum, like this:

```
for subset in powerset(L):
    if sum(subset) <= S:
        yield subset
```

But this may be very wasteful, since the number of subsets may be very large, and only a small number of them have a sum of at most S. What is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all subsets with `sums <= S` but note that storing them might require a lot of space. For "dense" subset sum distribution we can use a list, where `A[k]` keeps list of subsets with sum `k`. For sparse sums it would be better to use dictionary where `dict[key]` keeps list of subsets with sum `key` (remember copy of dictionary for every x, update dictionary adding x to existing subsets from that copy)

```
L = [1,3,5,8,11,17, 19, 23]
S = 15
A = [[] for _ in range(S+1)]
A[0] = [[0]]  #fake item to make non-zero list
for x in L:
    for ss in range(S, x-1,-1):
        l = len(A[ss-x])
        if len(A[ss-x]):
            for Y in A[ss-x]:
                A[ss].append(Y + [x])
for a in A:
    for b in a:
        if len(b) > 1:
            print(b[1:], end = ',')
    print()
[1],

[3],
[1, 3],
[5],
[1, 5],

[3, 5],[8],
[1, 3, 5],[1, 8],

[3, 8],[11],
[1, 3, 8],[1, 11],
[5, 8],
[1, 5, 8],[3, 11],
[1, 3, 11],
```